# Mysql Deidentify names of users

Tags: mysql

I am trying to deidentify names of users for use in a test instance. I am referring to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql).
And so far my code looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_client_copy2 VALUES (id, f_name, m_name, l_name, dob); -- leaving out the number plate
SELECT @lid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE tbl_client_copy2 SET f_name=concat(
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand()*36+1, 1),
  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', RAND(@seed)*36+1, 1)
)
WHERE id<@lid;
```

I keep getting this error :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_client_copy2 VALUES (id, f_name, m_name, l_name, dob)
> 1305 - FUNCTION ushauri_dod.RANDSTRING does not exist
```

I am looking for newer methods to replace the names, any useful references will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your intent for `RAND(@seed)`?  It may be hurting your goal, not helping.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to match your code.

Comment: Please provide all your requirements:  No dups?  "Next name unpredictable?  Cannot reconstruct original value?  Max of 8 characters?  Less than 8 is OK? Just capitals?  Just letters?

Comment: *I keep getting this error* There is no reference to `RANDSTRING` function in shown code. So investigate triggers defined on this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn a string of letters (or letters+digits) for (say, for a vehicle license plate) into another string with these attributes:

- Given the *same* input string, you get the same encrypted string.  (This lets you see that the same plate is showing up twice.)
- There is no practical way to convert the encrypted string back into the original.

  ```
    UPPER(LEFT(MD5(plate), 8))
  ```

(What 8 is the number of letters and digits desired.)

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT UPPER(LEFT(MD5('ABCDE'), 8));
+------------------------------+
| UPPER(LEFT(MD5('ABCDE'), 8)) |
+------------------------------+
| 2ECDDE39                     |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT UPPER(LEFT(MD5('ABCDE'), 8));
+------------------------------+
| UPPER(LEFT(MD5('ABCDE'), 8)) |
+------------------------------+
| 2ECDDE39                     |  -- reproducable
+------------------------------+
```

- If you don't care about reproducibility, `RAND()` *without a seed* may be useful.
- If you need to retrieve the original, see `AES_ENCRYPT`, but there may be length constraints.

With most techniques, there is a chance that two different plates will be encrypted into the same string.

More in my fresh answer to that other Question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251271/1766831

Comment: @Akina - The left 8 of a Version 1 UUID is the low part of the time (down to 0.1us).  That part rolls over every minute or so.  That is, there is a tiny risk of a dup as soon as one(?) minute.

Comment: (Correction -- repeats every approx. 7 minutes.)